# Setting a 'published_on' date field in a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my 2nd day playing with Ruby on Rails, so please be gentle :)

I have a very (hopefully) simple question: I want to set a publish date on my model, when it is indeed being created. I am using Mongoid, and it looks like this:

```
class Page
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :content, type: String
  field :title, type: String
  field :published_on, type: DateTime
end
```

Here is the question: should I set the `published_on` field from the `create` action, just before the call to `@page.save`? Or is there a better, more idiomatic way?

If I do it like that, meaning, calling `@page.published_on = Date.now` from within the controller's action, I get a warning:

> Cannot find 'published_on=' for type 'Page'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put

```
class Page
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
```

you get the rails automagic fields `created_at` and `updated_at`

Comment: I would expect that a Page could be created_at or updated_at a different date than when it's published_on.

Comment: Isn't created_at being set when it is written into MongoDB, and not when the object is actually created?

Comment: You said " I want to set a publish date on my model, when it is indeed being created" Are you asking about when a Page is created, or will it be published at a later date?

Comment: No no, I definitely asked about when a page is being created. But you were downvoted, so I wonder why...